# Remove headers row of all excel files except the first file when combines multiple excel files using POWER Query

Tags: excel

Requirement: I have to **combine all the excel files** which are available in a single folder. But I have to **use only the header row of the first excel file and discard the header row of the remaining excel files using GUI**. I am using **POWER QUERY**.

I am able to combine all the excel files and also able to use to header of the first excel file using the GUI **"Use the first row as header"**. but could not able to remove or discard the header row of remaining files. I have to remove them manually.
Any help to resolve the issue would be appreciated.

Advance thanks to all

Comment: You may want to share your PQ code, then it’s more clear what you want to do. What do you mean by removing manually? Like directly in the resulting table and not within the PQ code? In PQ all the tables have column headers (even if it is called column1). But no problem to append: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries

Comment: … assuming your xlsx files have the same column header names: After loading into PQ, you can make 1st row as header for all tables (so all tables have the specific names as headers) and then append. Alternatively, after loading into PQ, delete 1st row for all tables except for the first table (so all tables have the generic header naming like column1 and only in table1 the actual header name is still in the 1st row), then append, and then make 1st row to header (which will come from the 1st table).

Comment: I solved the problem by format the data as table  data and load using "Get Data from Folder" into the PQ and combined. No need to manually delete the header row of all files. Also remove, if we want, the table format after the combined the excel files. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Yes, when your source is already defined as table, PQ will do “automatically” assign the corresponding line as header after loading. Also the append query will handle the table headers properly as described in the link. Cheers!